# SQL updates to data layed out as linked list

Tags: sql, oracle, join

*** Updated, clarified question and example**

I have a table that has data represented as a linked list

ie:

ID|FROM_STATE|TO_STATE|SOME_OTHER_COLUMN

I need to change the "pointers" around to remove the state of BAR. As you see below, foo goes to bar and bar goes to com etc. I want foo to go directly to com and from QUAX to FIZZ. Additionally, the value from "SOME_OTHER_COLUMN" needs to be picked up from the record being removed and used in place of the value for "SOME_OTHER_COLUMN" on the record being updated.

FROM

```
ID|FROM_STATE|TO_STATE|SOME_OTHER_COLUMN
 1| FOO      | BAR    | xxx
 1| BAR      | COM    | zzz
 2| QUAZ     | BAR    | aaa
 2| BAR      | FIZZ   | bbb
```

TO:

```
ID|FROM_STATE|TO_STATE|SOME_OTHER_COLUMN
 1| FOO      | COM    | zzz
 2| QUAX     | FIZZ   | bbb
```

I started by writing a self join and trying something like:

```
update 
FOO a
    join FOO b 
      on a.ID = b.ID
     and a.FROM_STATE = b.FROM_STATE

  set a.TO_STATE = b.TO_STATE
where b.FROM_STATE='BAR'
  and a.TO_STATE='BAR';
```

That didn't work, no rows were changed.

I've setup my table in the below SQLFilldle. Any help is appreciated. DB is oracle (don't have the version)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e8d08/1

Comment: Based on your description result: `1| FOO      | BAR    | xxx` should actually be  `1| FOO      | COM    | xxx` ???

Comment: All IDs are equal to 1, and a.FROM_STAGE might be a.FROM_STATE?

Comment: @AaronLS, yes it was a typo. Thanks for catching it

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 queries, an update and a delete.

```
UPDATE tbl t SET (To_State,SomeColumn) = 
 (SELECT To_State, SomeColumn
  FROM tbl
  WHERE From_State = t.To_State
  AND Id = t.Id)
WHERE To_State = ?
AND Id = ?;

DELETE FROM tbl
WHERE From_State = ?
AND Id = ?;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have a lot of rows and don't really want to have to go through and identify the ID numbers on each that fit the pattern and then enumerate them in a where clause.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with 'go through each row'. You simply pass the linked list id and from_state of the row you want to remove. If you're trying to do something other than that you should update your question.

Comment: I don't know the ID of every row I want to remove, I supose I could try somehting like where ID in (select ID ....)

Comment: I get an error when trying your query - "single-row subquery returns more than one row".

Comment: That means that (ID,From_State) is not unique for the table, which I assumed. My assumption: table holds multiple linked lists, identified by ID. Every list has a number of items, identified by From_State. Or are you not really talking about a Linked List, but a Tree instead? If my asummption is incorrect, please update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
 update 
 FOO a
join FOO b 
  on a.ID = b.ID
 and a.FROM_STATE = b.FROM_STATE

set a.TO_STATE = b.TO_STATE
where b.FROM_STATE = a.TO_STATE;
```

Comment: It might be useful to include an explanation how this is different than what OP tried and is an answer to the question.